# MySQLI_ASSOC to JS array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, mysqli

I'm trying to put this Assoc array from PHP and send it to JS to use it with the google maps api. The code that I have since know is this:

Marker.php

```
<?php
$config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
$sql = "SELECT `secName` , `secLat` , `secLng` FROM `guia_sectors`";

if (!$mysqli = new mysqli ($config['HOST'], $config['USER'], $config['PASSWORD'], $config['DB']))
{
    echo "MySQLI Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

for ($i = 0; $i < $result->num_rows; $i++) {
    echo json_encode($result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
}

?>
```

JS

```
function getMarker () {
$.get ('includes/marker.php', function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

}

this is the array that I'm getting from Marker.php, I need to use the Lat and Lng:

```
{"secName":"aosindaiosdn","secLat":"-54.74584205236408","secLng":"-68.19616198539734"}{"secName":"JAsud","secLat":"-54.74584205236408","secLng":"-68.19616198539734"}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've found the answer. The problem was that I was sending the assoc array wrong.

The solution is to do this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT...');

$rows = array();
while ($r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jQuery just use `anArray=$.parseJSON(data);`
Then acces `anArray[0].secLat`

Comment: I'm getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting that error when I do:

    function getMarker () {
 $.get ('includes/marker.php', function (data) {
  var markers = $.parseJSON(data);

  //alert(obj);
 });
}